# How do i pass a Json object to the Jquery dialog?

Tags: jquery

i have a `table` of rows with `hyperlinks`, when i click a row link, it sends the row data to a `jquery Dialog`. I'm planning to send the data as `json` but how do i send the `json` object to the dialog and extract and place data in the fields?

Is it common to send row data as Json to a dialog like this?

I my app the dialog's fields are hard coded to the  in the html area. but should i hard code it in html area or should i add field's html code from Javascript?

Comment: A  `jquery dialog` is html - how are you expecting something that expects html to magically to handle something other than html?   Would you expect it handle xml? base64/sha-1 encoded string?    If you actually mean your jquery dialog code, then it's your code, you make it do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

**I know this should be a comment, but i do not have rights to comment yet as i joined yesterday, but still want OP to have this information so shorthand i added this as an answer.**

I've had a hard time understanding what your question and tags have in common, and what you exactly are trying to achieve. If you can, please rephrase your question, and add the code you are asking about.

Addtionally i want to clarify that jQuery - as you added it as a tag - has nothing to do with your attempt, as JSON is native JavaScript. JSON is a **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation and is in Javascript nothing more than a `object`!

Comment: FYI this should be a comment, not an answer (I've not flagged it, but someone will)

Comment: HI, yes sorry i just joined SO yesteday and cannot add comments, i will add this to the answer so i can give him this information and still not be bashed (hopefully).

Comment: @Tarekis to simplify i have built an Json object with data in a row. I need to send this object to JQuery dialog so i can display the data on the dialog

Comment: Okay, please show me your code with any data you pass and how you want it to be displayed, it sounds like it can be easily achieved.